# How to minimize Tomcat auto-deploy time / distraction?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, redeploy

I'm working on a small servlet-based application with rapid build/deploy/test turn-around.  I am finding that the wait time during development for Tomcat 8.0 to auto redeploy (with Host setting 'autoDeploy=true') is quite distracting: it varies between almost immediate and nearly 10 seconds.

I'd like (roughly in order of preference) to:

- Configure Tomcat to check for redeployments on every request.
- Reduce the time Tomcat waits before polling for redeployments (to, say, 1s).
- Or, alternatively, have a convenient way to prompt Tomcat to redeploy immediately as soon as the .war is built.  (I'm building/deploying with Ant.)

I've been searching the Tomcat documentation (and SO) for the last 30 minutes and don't see anything for any of these.  Am I missing something?

Can anyone recommend an approach (re one of the above) that they found minimized the turn-around time (and distraction)?

Comment: Tried JRebel or Spring Boot devtools ?

Comment: Spring Boot probably won't help - I'm not using Spring and I'm working with an in-house Java Web/MVC library (based loosely on Clojure/Ring/Compojure).  JRebel may be interesting.  (But, then again, I sort of *do* want it to redeploy - not just dynamically reload modified classes.)

Comment: Use an IDE.  They can hotdeploy.